# scrolling in outlook web using selenium to store a contact directory

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web, outlook

trying to programmatically scroll through about 8k contacts in a directory on outlook using selenium. Ive been able to login and navigate to the contacts directory, then I do this:

```
all_contacts = []
ycord = []
for contact in contacts:
    try:
        new_contact = contact.get_attribute("aria-label").split(',')
        new_contact[2] = new_contact[1].split('@')[0]
        all_contacts.append(new_contact)
        locationy = contact.location['y']
        ycord.append(locationy)
        #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(309, ycord[-1]);")
    except:
        continue
```

the issue now is the scrolling. what is the best way to scroll thru an 8000 line list of contacts?

I have tried to use the typical selenium scroll features (scroll to x,y or window scroll) but they do not seem to work well. The contacts page scroller is very senstive so manually coding in a fixed scroll amount is also difficult. Plus I need to add a timer pause after every scroll so that the website can buffer

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Comment: Try to scroll to an element by using `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', element)`